# Django state-based url routing

Tags: python, django, url-routing

**Hello!**

I would love for a django app I am developing to route a URL to a response based on logic beyond just the URL string.

I would like to be able to take the state of the application (the logged in user and their session, the contents of the database) into account. This would mean that two users could visit exactly the same URL, but based on the type of account they have (for instance) they would receive different responses.

**An example**

Say my app has `User` and `Admin` user classes. They both will frequently visit `http://some-domain.com/dashboard`, but they will see *entirely* different things there. Furthermore, there will be sub-urls beyond `dashboard` like `/dashboard/comments`, `/dashboard/friends`. Again, these will be entirely different views depending on the user class.

At present I do something like this:

(urls.py)

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^dashboard/', include([
        url(r'^$', render_dashboard),
        url(r'^settings/$', render_dashboard_settings),
        url(r'^friends/$', render_dashboard_friends),
    ])),
]
```

The issue with this setup is that there is no way to take the current user into account. It can still be made to work because I can route all kinds of user accounts to the same template, and use `{% if ... %}` statements there to provide different content to different users. I could also make the name of the template that ought to be rendered dynamic, in the call to `django.shortcuts.render`. But neither of these things are what I want. I want to be able to differentiate between users at an earlier level of URL mapping.

**My question**

What I *do* want to do is extend the functionality of the `url` method to take state into account, and route based on that functionality. Ideally, something like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    user_class_based_url(r'', {

        'Admin': include([
            url(r'^dashboard/', include([
                url(r'^$', render_admin_dashboard),
                url(r'^settings/$', render_admin_dashboard_settings),
                url(r'^friends/$', render_admin_dashboard_friends),
            ])),
        ]),

        'User': include([
            url(r'^dashboard/', include([
                url(r'^$', render_user_dashboard),
                url(r'^settings/$', render_user_dashboard_settings),
                url(r'^friends/$', render_user_dashboard_friends),
            ])),
        ]),

        'SomeOtherUserClass': include([.....]),
    }),
]
```

Now, different renderer functions are being called for the same url, but different user classes. Unfortunately, `user_class_based_url` is something I have totally made up. Ideally, `user_class_based_url` would be a custom function I could write. That way I could write other similar functions that take the app's state into account in other ways.

QUESTION: *Is there any way I can get this functionality?*

**In response to "you shouldn't even be designing it this way"**

The example I have given is contrived to get my question across more quickly. I want the functionality I have described because it would be incredibly helpful in many ways for the app I am building, and I am sure it would be a better approach than the alternative.

**Note**

I am already using django rest framework, in case that can be used to implement this design.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, I've solved this problem with completely custom code that allows me to develop using exactly the pattern I said I was looking for in this question. I will post it as an answer if anyone wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any way to do this in Django at the moment. Recently, there has been [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/django-developers/url%7Csort:date/django-developers/WQoJN_MGTOg/5sBjDw3VK0QJ) about creating a new API for the url dispatcher, but any changes would be in a future version of Django.

Answer (score 2):

If you want different templates for the same URL pattern, don't hardcode the templates in `urls.py`. Instead, route to a [view function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/views/) (or, alternatively, to a [class-based view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/)) in `views.py` that does the dispatching to different templates based on your criteria. This is exactly what `views.py` is intended for and how it is usually used.

For how to route an URL to a view function, best consult the [Django tutorial part 3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial03/). (If you're learning Django, you might want to [start](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/) at part 1.)

Adapting [the example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial03/#a-shortcut-render) from when the `render` shortcut is introduced in the tutorial, a view that dispatches to different templates could look something like this:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Question


def index(request):
    if request.user.is_admin():
        return render(request, 'polls/admin-index.html', {})
    else:
        latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
        context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
        return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)
```

Comment: But the way I see it, the url routing logic isn't a "view" and for that reason I naturally hesitate to put it inside `views.py`. I'd prefer to figure out which view I finally want to access outside of any views. Still - I'm interested in how you would go about using views to achieve this. Could you possibly post some example code? Thanks!

Comment: Don't read to much into names of a framework's concept. A Django 'view' roughly corresponds to a Rails 'controller', while a Django 'template' is more like a Rails 'view'. Other web-, frontend- and GUI-frameworks use the same terms with yet different meanings and probably none with exactly the meaning these terms have in the well-established [Model-View-Controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller). When learning a framework, get used to its concepts and terminology, but keep in mind they might be framework-specific.

Comment: cool, understood. I would love some basic example code though, just to get started! I've already read through the views tutorials you've linked, I'd just like some help with leveraging views to solve this specific design problem.

Comment: Remember that views are just functions that receive a request and return a response. It's perfectly acceptable to make a "router view" that simply returns the response of another view based on some condition. The new API that allows this in the url dispatcher itself won't be ready until 1.9 or 2.0.

Comment: Ok, cool. I realize that's an option - the thing I worry about losing if I implement my own method of url handling is django's ability to reverse urls, e.g. for use with `{% url 'some-url-name' %}`. I suppose I could also rewrite that functionality on my own...? Do you think it would be worthwhile losing that `reverse` functionality?

Comment: If I understand your use-case correctly, `reverse()` doesn't have to differentiate between different users, as the url itself is the same. If it is, it will always route to the same view that routes the request to another view, so reversing won't be a problem.

Comment: To be clear: Don't create a catch-all route and then parse URLs in its view function. Only the decisions that cannot be determined by the URL should be made in the view function. For different URL patterns, you should still use different routes that either directly route to a template or to route-specific view functions that does the further dispatching. This way, `reverse()` will still give you valuable and meaningful results.